# Help determining if a finite subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

> If $\{A_n \; : \; n \in \mathbb N\}$ is any collection of subsets of $\mathbb R$, with each set $A_n$ containing finitely many numbers, then the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is closed and bounded.

I need to determine if this is true or false and if true prove it, if false provide a counter-example.

I believe this is a true statement because every finite subset of $\mathbb R$ is a bounded set, but I'm not sure if it is a closed set?  I imagine it too is closed because every limit point would be in $S$.

Assuming this is true, how would I start off proving it?

> If $(r_n)$ is any Cauchy sequence of real numbers and $(s_n)$ is any increasing sequence of negative numbers, then the sequence $(r_n-s_n)$ converges.

I'm confused by this one because is $s_n$ "increasing" negatively or positively?  In other words if I'm at $-1000$ is my sequence heading towards $0$ or $-100000$?  What does increasing mean in this context?

Since it requires a Cauchy sequence of $\mathbb R$ a good example would would be $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: "I believe this is a true statement because every finite subset of R is a bounded set"  Whoa!  *THINK* about that.  This is an *infinite* union so it need not be finite.  Do you still think it must be bounded?  Hint:  Is $\mathbb N = \cup_{i \in \mathbb N} \{i\}$ bounded?

Comment: The second is confusing but increasing means.. increasing.  As 0 > negative anything, it means going toward the zero.  If it we becoming *absolutely larger* then it is obviously false.  But as an *increasing* negative sequence is becoming *absolutely smaller* then this sequence is bounded above by zero.  Which might make this reasonably true.

Comment: In two $r_n$ converges because it is cauchy.  $s_n$ is increasing and bounded above by 0.  What does that tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A_n = \{ n \}$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \mathbb{N}$ which is not bounded so the union need to be bounded but it is closed in this case.

If $A_n = \{ \frac{1}{n} \}$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is bounded but not closed ($0$ is a limit point).

It is a good exercise to construct an example of $A_n$ in which $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is not closed and also not bounded at the same time.

Comment: Awesome explanation!  It took me about 25 minutes to understand what you were saying, but now I totally get it.  Part 1 is false because of your examples.

Answer (score 1):

1) Hint:  Any countable subset $V \subset \mathbb R$ can be written as $V = \cup_{v_i \in V} \{v_i\}$ *any* countable set can be such a union.

Are all countable subsets of $\mathbb R$ closed and bounded? Can you prove it? Can you find a counter example?

(Your reasoning that if every finite set is something then a countable union of finite sets is something is just plain wrong.  An obvious example is every finite set is finite but a countable union of finite sets is not.  Bounded and finite are very similar concepts.)

2) Increasing means $a_{i+1} > a_i$.  As $-999 > -10000$ we are going toward the zero.  (The statement is obviously false otherwise).

So the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is increasing yet also negative.  What does that tell you?  It's heading toward zero.  Does it ever get to zero?  Does it ever get above zero?  What's the terminology for that?  What does that imply about the sequence $\{s_n\}$?

Comment: For 2) So you're saying $0$ is a boundary point of $s_n$ and so the sequence converges.  This means the second one is true.  I'm still trying to digest part 1) as I don't completely understand yet

Comment: No.  0 does not need to be a boundary point of $s_n$.  But 0 is an upper bound.  Not nescessarily the *least* upper bound but *an* upper bound.  You should know a theory about increasing bounded real sequences.  Take $a_n = -7 - 1/n$.  It is negative and increasing but it doesn't converge to 0.

Comment: Let V = {v_1,v_2, v_3 .....} be a countable set.  Then $V = \cup_{i\in \mathbb N}\{v_i\}$.  This is a union of finite sets.  Does it have to be closed and bounded?  In $N = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7....} = \cup_{i \in N}\{i\}$ closed and bounded? Is $\mathbb Q = \cup_{q \in \mathbb Q}\{q\}$ closed and bounded?

Comment: For your first comment, an increasing bounded real sequences converges to a real number.  In your example, $a_n$ converges to $-7$.  So for part 2 since $r_n$ and $s_n$ converge to real numbers, the difference between them is also a real number.

Comment: Definitions and results:  i) the real numbers have the least upper bound property.  ii) {s_n} is bounded so there exists a real number $w = \sup\{s_n\}$.  iii) For all $\epsilon > 0$ $w - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound. iv) there is an $w - \epsilon < s_i$.  iv) for all n > i $w - \epsilon < s_i < s_n \le w$.  v) $\{s_n\} \rightarrow w$.

Comment: Hmmm... close enough.  The difference of converging sequences converge (to the difference of the limits).  r_n converges because it is cauchy.  s_n converges because it is increasing and bounded above.  so r_n - s_n converges.